# Is there a switch / capability to disable automatic screenshot capture with chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a bit stuck.
When I interact with a page I might try to click an element which is covered by another element.

Chromedriver raises an exception

> "ClickElement unknown error: Element .... is not clickable at point (190, 567).
>   Other element would receive the click:  "

I'm using JSONWired protocol and result of the `/click` command is a huge JSON which contains all the fields described here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#failed-commands, including `screen` property which is a screenshot of that page.

Is there a switch or a setting or a flag or something to disable obtaining the screenshot when exception is raised? The page is quite big and it takes 3-4 seconds to get the screenshot. I just don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling this method, which waits until ajax is idle, before attempting to click your web element:

```
public static void waitForJQueryToBeActive() {
    Boolean isJqueryUsed = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return (typeof(jQuery) != 'undefined')");
    if (isJqueryUsed) {
        while (true) {
            // JavaScript test to verify jQuery is active or not
            Boolean ajaxIsComplete = (Boolean) (((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                    .executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
            if (ajaxIsComplete)
                break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 

I was quite uncertain of what "this behaviour" means. I need to disable automatic screenshoting whenever Chromedriver raises an exception, that's what am I trying to prevent.

Comment: I'm not sure how a screenshot would block access to web elements, and based on the error you're reporting, that is what is going on.  It's been my experience with this particular error message that a non-visible object is deliberately placed over a web element, or sometimes the entire screen.  I'm not aware of any automatic screenshot behavior of Chrome or any other browser that gets triggered upon exceptions.  I would think that would be more likely a part of your own company's framework, perhaps?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's definitely not a part of our framework. 

Please, take a look: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#failed-commands 

The "screen" property is optional, yet it is returned by Chromedriver. The case when we're trying to click an overlapped element is exactly the case of a "failed" command.

Comment: The screenshot does not block anything. The thing is it takes quite significant amount of time to obtain the screenshot and to deliver it from a selenium node to a test.
I simply don't need this screenshot as I ignore it. But, again, it takes 3-7 seconds to send over. That means every time I ignore that message I wait for 3-7 seconds.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your situation better, and my offered solution is therefore no help.  Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions.